# Why does using sys.argv[1] turn my printed strings into printed tuples of strings?

Tags: python

The output before I used sys.argv[1], and hardcoded my arguments was in variables was :

```
Plugin ID:  some_number_1
Plugin Name:  some_sentence_1
---------------------------------------------
Plugin ID:  some_number_2
Plugin Name:  some_sentence_2
---------------------------------------------
```

and now when I use sys.argv[1] it is:

```
('Plugin ID: ', u'some_number_1')
('Plugin Name: ', u'some_sentence_1')
---------------------------------------------
('Plugin ID: ', u'some_number_2')
('Plugin Name: ', u'some_sentence_2')
```

Note: Before I added sys.argv, I was running directly using the 'run' button in PyCharm. Now, with sys.argv and accepting an argument via command line, ofcourse I run the file via the command line. This seems to be the reason it happens... but why? And how do I make it so I can accept an argument in command line without turning my strings into tuples.

Comment: That would depend on the code producing this output, which you neglected to include.

Comment: We can't help unless you show us what you're doing with the args in your code.

Comment: You're somehow running the code under Python 2.x now, which has a `print` statement that works rather differently than the 3.x version.